# Oracle 11g: ORA-12505 Error after reinstalling DB

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following problem:

On my local machine, I had an installation of Oracle 11g and I had an old connection in which I had some tables for later use. I somehow forgot the system password of this old installation, therefore uninstalled it and then installed it anew, with a new system password taken in the installation.

Now in the Sql Developer, I am seeing the following error:
[image]

Here is what I have done:

1) The database connection I want to reach is "CorpusNew". It had an user name: RLINKAGE and since after reinstalling the DB all users have been reset, I created a new user RLINKAGE and gave it all privileges.

2)Then I tried to connect my old db from the previous 11g installation, entered the new username-password pair, but then I get the ORA-12505 error.

I tried all the googling I can, but I could not find an answer to this problem. I think I somehow need to point my new DB installation to location of this old DB. I don't think it has been deleted with the uninstall, since I can still see it in the Sql Developer.

I am direly in need help...

Comment: You would need to ensure that the connection parameters (host, port and sid) for the old connection map to your new database instance.  You should be able to see this in the connection property in SQL Developer and then match it to what is in the TNSNAMES.ora in the Oracle installation folder.   Also unsure if you need the data from the older tables, which you most probably have lost if you did a re-install.

Comment: Check your database `SID` (`echo $ORACLE_SID` for *nix OS) and compare it with SID in properties of a DB connection in SQLDeveloper.